# How to preview MP3s in the Preview Pane *without* WMP as default player?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, mp3, windows-media-player

I use Audacity as my audio file Open default, but I'd like to be able to preview MP3s in the Preview pane of the File Explorer. If I set my file open default to Audacity, I lose the Preview ability.

Is there any way to retain the Preview ability in the Preview Pane without having WMP set as my default MP3 app?

Comment: How exactly did you associate MP3 files with Audacity?

Comment: Right-click, "Open With," Choose Program, Audacity.exe, "Always use this program to open this type of file". That may not be the perfect phrasing -- I'm at work and on a Mac at the moment, so I can't check all the prompts in Win7.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ticking `Always use this program to open this type of file` indeed breaks the Preview pane for MP3 files (and possibly other file types too).

As a workaround, I suggest that you instead use the [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) tool to associate MP3 files with Audacity. In FileTypesMan, first double-click the `.mp3` entry, clear the `User Choice` and click `OK`. Then right-click in the lower pane, add a new action for Audacity, and mark it as the default action.